# Why isn't guard let foo = foo valid?

Tags: swift

In Swift, you can use if let optional binding to unwrap an optional into a constant or variable with the same name:

```
func test()
{
  let a: Int? = 1

  if let a = a {
    print("a = \(a)")
  } 
}
```

For everything inside the `if let` statement, the optional `a` is unwrapped into a regular int.

Likewise, I can use a guard statement to achieve a similar effect

```
func test()
{
  let a: Int? = 1

  guard let requiredA = a else{
    return
  }
  print("a = \(requiredA)")
}
```

However, I can't use code like this: `guard let a = a else`:

```
func test()
{
  let a: Int? = 1

  guard let a = a else{
    return
  }
  print("a = \(a)")
}
```

Why not?

In a guard statement, if the conditional of the guard statement fails, the else clause is executed and you exit the current scope. If the conditional succeeds, a new variable/constant is created from guard statement's closing brace to the end of the current scope.

Why can't I do the same trick of mapping an optional into a variable/constant with the same name for remainder of the current scope?

**P.S.:** I realize this question isn't a perfect fit for this site. I'm open to suggestions as to where would be a better place for this question.

Comment: Looks to me like the `if` way creates two variables in different scopes, which is fine, while the `guard` way would be creating two identically-named variables in the same scope, which would be a weird special case and complicate the variable resolution rules to allow it. I'm guessing, though; I don't know Swift.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason you can't do this:

```
func test()
{
  let a: Int? = 1

  guard let a = a else{
    return
  }
  print("a = \(a)")
}
```

is because `guard` creates the new variable in the same scope, thus you have two variables called `a` in the same scope.  One is an `Int` and the other is an `Int?`.  That is not allowed.

The error that you get **Definition conflicts with previous value** is exactly the same as if you had done this:

```
func test()
{
    let a: Int? = 1

    let a = a!
}
```

---

Compare that with:

```
func test()
{
    let a: Int? = 1

    if let a = a {
        print("a = \(a)")
    }
}
```

In this case, the new variable `a` which is an `Int` exists only in the new scope of the `if`'s then clause, so this works.

---

From the comments:

> But I submit to you that the section of code after the closing brace
>   and to the end of the enclosing scope is actually an inner scope.

I can understand that you would like it to be so, but it isn't.  If that were the case, then you could do this, but it too gives an error:

```
func test()
{
    let a: Int? = 1

    guard let b = a else{
        return
    }
    print("b = \(b)")

    let a = 5  // Definition conflicts with previous value

    print("a = \(a)")
}
```

The beauty of `guard` is that it doesn't create new scopes and you avoid creating the *pyramid of death* that results when you repeatedly use `if let` to unwrap optionals (and in the process create new scopes).

---

See the follow-up question 
[When did guard let foo = foo become legal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41854162/1630618) for more insight on this topic.

Comment: But I submit to you that the section of code after the closing brace and to the end of the enclosing scope is actually an inner scope. If you create a new variable/constant, it exists from that point until the end of the current scope. How is that different from `if let`, where inside the body of the statement, the local definition of `a` overrides the outer definition?

Comment: It is different than `if let` because `if let` the  `{ }` which follows `if let` creates a new scope.  The beauty of `guard` is that you don't have `{ }` and thus avoid the pyramid of death of new scopes.

Comment: @DuncanC `if let` is quite different. Try this: `if let b = a { ... } let b = 4`. The 2nd `b` is fine because the `b` from the `if let` is no longer in scope.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that makes sense. It makes the pattern you use different than `if let`, and leads to some awkward naming, like `reqiredA` in my example.

Comment: @DuncanC Or just use `if let a = a { rest of code }` instead of `guard... return`.

Comment: Sure, but that ends up with ever-increasing levels of nesting, and doesn't give you the "golden path" advantages that you get with `guard`

Comment: Got the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58226900/swift-cant-unwrap-an-optional-inside-a-loop but I can't understand why it is not working event with this nice explanation.

Comment: Actually, I can do that code you posted with the `guard` and it runs without problems in XCode 13.1

Comment: @vacawama I think the first example form your question get compiled (now) but the variable `a` is unwrapped in its initial scope