# conflict with previous value in same-name Shadowing

Tags: swift, guard, variable-declaration

I'm reading from [Erica Sadun's Swift Style book](http://ericasadun.com/2016/12/14/buy-a-book-swift-style/) and playing around with some code.

She suggests:

> Prefer using same-name shadowing in conditional bind. “This approach is both conventional and safe:
>
> guard​ ​let​ x = x { ... } ​// yes​
>
> guard​ ​let​ y = x { ... } ​// no​
>
> Deliberate same-name shadowing ensures the the unwrapped value’s role follows the logical intent established by the name prior to the if or guard statement. Introducing a new name blurs the line of those semantics and can prove dangerous. Consistent same-named shadowing prevents you from adding an unintentional shadow to symbols in the parent scope.

Regardless of this being a good opinion or not:

In my code, I'm trying to do:

```
guard let data = data else{...}
```

but I get the following error:

> Definition conflicts with previous value

A simplified version of my function is:

```
func process(){
  data : AnyObject?

  if x == nil{ data = m}
  else if x > 5{ data = j}
  guard let data = data else { return } // Definition conflicts with previous value
  somefunc(data)
}
```

If I place the guard statement inside the `if` or `else if` then the error would go away. But that's not what I want.

Is there any workaround to still be able to do same-name shadow.

**EDIT:**
I tried using backticks and I get the following errors:
[image]

> - Expected Pattern
> - Braced block of statements is an unused closure

Comment: try `guard let ``data`` = data` <- data in "`", dunno how to avoid stack overflow forcing them to be code borders

Comment: @JuicyFruit do you mean place 2 backticks before and after the first `data`? I tried. Didn't work. Got a different error. See my edit

Comment: 1 backtick each side, didn't know how this symbol is called, sry

Comment: @JuicyFruit I still get error: Definition conflicts with previous value

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41854162/when-did-guard-let-foo-foo-become-legal

Comment: @rmaddy this embarrassing. I've already mentioned that exactly in my **own** answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39263210/5175709). See The part where I say: "Guard creates a new variable"

Comment: Are you sure Erica isn't talking about `if let` and not `guard let`?

Comment: @rmaddy yes 100% sure. That code snippet is copy/pasted from her book

Comment: You might want to format the book quotes using > so it shows as a quote.

Comment: @rmaddy to be precise she mentions it for both `if let` & `guard let`