# Why is it not a compile error if i redefine a method parameter?

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

I had a bug in my code and it turned out that I redefined a method parameter in the method's code without realising that. I would expect a compiler error, but I did not get that:

```
func someMethod(parameter:Int)
{
 let parameter = 10 //Why does this not result in error?
}
```

I understand that you can do `parameter = 10`, but I don't understand why `let parameter = 10` is valid.

Is there a good reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/41854162/2976878 – Swift treats the function parameters as being in a higher scope to the function body. Therefore because you can redefine things in a lower scope, you can redefine the parameters in the function body itself.

Comment: @Hamish Ok, that explains it a bit. Thanks. However, I can imagine it is a cause of bugs that are not easy to catch, since there is no warning or so. And that is a bit weird for a language as Swift, that focuses really hard on handling everything correctly.

Comment: In fact `parameter = 10` would result in an error since `parameter` is immutable.  You used to be able to mark the parameter as `var` like this `func someMethod(var parameter: Int)` but that was removed.  Now you do it like this: `func someMethod(parameter: Int) { var parameter = parameter ... }`.

Comment: @vacawama that's not correct, I just tried the `let parameter = parameter` and it works without compiler warnings or errors.

Comment: I didn't say `let parameter = parameter`; I said `parameter = 10` without the let won't work because `parameter` is immutable.

Comment: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59308252dc856e5eaf334094

Comment: @vacawama Ok, sorry, Now I understand what you were saying. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary reason that comes to mind is it allows for `if let` and `guard let` to work the way it does, but this capability is useful in many different circumstances.

In some ways this isn't ideal and can potentially cause errors, but there is at least a consistent rule that applies and you can get used to:

> Variable names defined outside of the current scope, (i.e. `{}`), can be re-defined.

This applies within class/struct methods, as well as closures, internal functions, etc.

It's the reason this doesn't work:

```
func testFunc(test: String) {
    var test: Int? = 2
    guard let test = test else {
        return
    }
}
```

But this does:

```
func testFunc(test: String) {
    var test: Int? = 2
    if let test = test  {
        return
    }
}
```